# Select row in UITableView

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm pretty new to xcode development and I cannot figure out how to select a row and give label/action I want. I'm using something i found on the internet, sample code with a customized uitableview with 3 rows:

```
opLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HeliosMedica",[indexPath section]];
bottomLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Centrumedical.", [indexPath section]];
```

I want each row to have different content and also give them a hyperlink. Can anyone tell me where how I can do that.

Appreciate very much your help.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Apple Documents for [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You want to understand some of the basic methods there, including `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

You probably already have implemented some of the UITableView class methods, in order to get a table to just show up on our screen, including `numberOfSections`, `numberOfSections:`and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. These are called by the tableview object and your code executes to meet the tableView's needs.

Here is some sample code you can start with to open a url when the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:method is executed.

```
myURL = [arrayOfURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

You will have to initialize the array, first.